# 'bis' oder 'bis zu(m)'

Tags: preposition

Welches ist richtig, und warum?

> (a) Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis 23 Grad.
>
> (b) Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis zu 23 Grad.
>
> (c) Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis zum 23 Grad.

Comment: Das ist inhaltlich ein bißchen kompliziert. Was möchtest du denn ausdrücken: Daß die Höchsttemperatur _genau_ 23 Grad sein wird, oder daß die Höchsttemperatur _höchstens_ 23 Grad sein wird (vielleicht aber auch nur 22 oder 21 Grad)?

Comment: @chirlu Ich möchte über alle Möglichkeiten wissen :)

Comment: "bis zu 23 Grad" or "bis auf 23 Grad"

Comment: @Em1: Aber nicht wie in Beispiel "b".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das ist ein bißchen kompliziert, und zwar wegen der Vielgestaltigkeit von *bis* wie auch der inhaltlichen Besonderheiten von Wettervorhersagen.

## bis

Das Wort *bis* kann Präposition sein, Konjunktion oder auch eine Partikel, die eine andere Präposition begleitet:

> Sie schlief bis Sonnenaufgang.
>   Sie schlief, bis die Sonne aufging.
>   Sie schlief bis zum Sonnenaufgang.

Alle drei Sätze bedeuten ungefähr dasselbe; es wird damit eine Grenze für den betrachteten Vorgang angegeben.

Wie man im ersten Beispielsatz sieht, steht *bis* als Präposition nie mit Artikel. Deshalb wird auch der zugehörige Kasus (Akkusativ) selten deutlich. Wenn es bei einer anderen Präposition steht, wie im dritten Beispielsatz (*zu*), gibt diese den Kasus vor.

*Bis* kann auch eine Spanne von Werten ausdrücken und ist dann gleichbedeutend mit *zwischen ... und*:

> Fünf bis zehn Minuten wird es noch dauern. Zwischen fünf und zehn Minuten wird es noch dauern.
>   Der Mann ist siebzig bis achtzig Jahre alt. Der Mann ist zwischen siebzig und achtzig Jahren alt.

## bis zu

Die feste Kombination *bis zu* kann bei Mengen/Werten eine Höchstgrenze angeben:

> Bis zu zehn Minuten wird es noch dauern. Der Mann ist bis zu achtzig Jahre alt.

Anders als bei der Präposition *bis* ist bei *bis zu* gerade nicht gesagt, daß die Grenze auch tatsächlich erreicht wurde.

In der Wendung *bis zu* ist *zu* keine Präposition (mehr). Man kann *bis zu* nach beliebigen Präpositionen verwenden, sogar nach *zu* (auch wenn das etwas seltsam klingt):

> Der Aufzug hat Platz *für* bis zu zehn Leute.
>   Der Aufzug kann *mit* bis zu zehn Leuten besetzt werden.
>   Der Aufzug hat eine Kapazität *von* bis zu zehn Leuten.
>   Man kann den Aufzug *zu* bis zu zehn Leuten benutzen.

Selten kann man bei einem *bis zu* das *zu* weglassen und bekommt so noch eine weitere Funktion für *bis*:

> Bis zehn Leute passen in den Aufzug.

## Temperaturvorhersagen

Speziell bei Temperaturvorhersagen hat man noch einige inhaltliche Besonderheiten, so daß man aus ganz unterschiedlichen Gründen vielleicht ein *bis* einbauen will:

- Die Vorhersage ist unsicher; die Temperatur könnte 21, 22 oder 23 Grad sein.
- Wettervorhersagen in der Zeitung, im Radio usw. beziehen sich auf große Gebiete, die Temperatur dort ist nicht überall gleich hoch.
- Auch an einem konkreten Ort ändern sich die Temperaturen im Tagesverlauf.

Was heißt das nun für die angefragten Sätze?

Der Satz (a) ist möglich, aber unüblich, und bedeutet, daß 23 Grad im Tagesverlauf tatsächlich erreicht werden. Strenggenommen muß das nicht die höchste Temperatur des Tages sein.

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis 23 Grad. (a)

Die normale Formulierung wäre allerdings diese, mit *auf*; ein *bis* kann dabei sein, muß es aber nicht:

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen (bis) auf 23 Grad.

Und wenn man sich nicht festlegen möchte, ob die 23 Grad wirklich erreicht werden, sagt man:

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen auf bis zu 23 Grad.

Der Satz (b) ist grammatisch möglich, aber meteorologisch zweifelhaft. (Obwohl, in manchen Wüstengebieten mag das gehen.) Er würde bedeuten, daß der *Unterschied* in der Temperatur (zu heute, oder zum frühen Morgen o.ä.) 23 Grad beträgt. Wenn man das wirklich ausdrücken will, würde man der Deutlichkeit halber *um* benutzen:

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis zu 23 Grad. (b)
>   Die Temperaturen steigen morgen um bis zu 23 Grad.

Der Satz (c) schließlich ist ungrammatisch. Eine Angabe wie *23 Grad* (*5 Liter*, *12 Kilometer*) steht normalerweise ohne Artikel, und wenn doch, dann wäre hier der Plural nötig (*die 23 Grad vom gestrigen Vormittag*). Aber auch dann wird *steigen* in diesem Zusammenhang nicht mit *zu* kombiniert.

Noch eine Anmerkung zum Schluß: Es gibt eigentlich keinen guten Grund, hier von *Temperaturen* im Plural zu sprechen, auch wenn das tatsächlich oft getan wird. Alle Sätze funktionieren auch im Singular (*Die Temperatur steigt*).

Comment: Ich realisier grade, dass mein Kommentar zu OPs Frage falsch ist, weil ich im Kopf hatte "bei Temperaturen bei bis zu 23 Grad". In Kombination mit "steigen" sieht das alles aber anders aus.

Comment: I still don't understand why "Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis zu 23 Grad. (b)" refers to the difference in temperature, instead of "The temperature tomorrow will rise up to at most 23 Grad." And how would one say that English sentence in German?

Comment: @Mika H.: Here, _bis zu_ corresponds to _at most_. _The temperature will rise at most 23 degrees_ also expresses a difference, just as in German. - The translation is already in the answer: _Die Temperaturen steigen morgen auf bis zu 23 Grad._

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean. If you want to say that the final temperature is 23°, use *bis auf* or *bis zu*:

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis *zu* 23 Grad
>   Die Temperaturen steigen morgen bis *auf* 23 Grad
>   Die Temperaturen steigen morgen *auf um* die 23 Grad

For precision, you can say

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen *auf genau* 23 Grad

But if you want to say that the difference between today's temperature and tomorrow's temperature is 23° (which from context is not very plausible, but grammatically allowed)

> Die Temperaturen steigen morgen um 23 Grad.

Comment: For estimation also possible "Die Temperaturen steigen morgen auf um die 23 Grad"

Comment: And you can add "If you want to be precise what the temperature will be exactly you can say *Die Temperature stiegen morgen auf (genau) 23 Grad.*"