# »Von Berlin bis Bodensee« - »bis« oder »bis zum«?

Tags: preposition

Vorbemerkung: Dieses scheinbare Duplikat - ['bis' oder 'bis zu(m)'](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/bis-oder-bis-zum) - fragt nach etwas anderem.

---

Heute wurde mir diese S.O. Werbung angezeigt:

[image: Stackoverflow Dev Ad 'Von Berlin bis Bodensee']

```
[ Von Berlin
  bis Bodensee ]
```

Da es sich beim Bodensee um ein Gewässer handelt und nicht um eine Stadt, halte ich die Werbung für grammatikalisch falsch. Ich *glaube* es müsste **Von Berlin bis *zum* Bodensee** heißen.

Ist diese Verkürzung irgendwie zulässig? Wenn ja, warum. Wenn nein, warum nicht?

Comment: "Irgendwie zulässig" wäre die Verkürzung, wenn die Werbung keinen geographischen sondern einen lexikalischen Bezug hätte. Natürlich wäre dann "B - B" etwas ungeschickt, von "A - Z" (Aachen bis Zwickau) wäre besser. Aber solche Werbung sieht man trotzdem vereinzelt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du hast recht, der See würde eigentlich einen Artikel benötigen. Im Internet findet man viele Quellen dazu, z.B. [Deutsche Grammatik 2.0](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/genus-artikel/genus-artikel-von-geographischen-namen/)

> ### Genus (Artikel) von geographischen Namen
>
> #### Städte- und Ländernamen
>
> Bei Städte- und Ländernamen wird normalerweise kein Genus markiert. 
>   (...)
>
> #### Andere geographische Namen
>
> Alle anderen geographischen Namen z. B. von Flüssen, Bergen oder Seen
>   haben einen Artikel.
>   (...)

### Aber

Prinzipiell, sozusagen als allerhöchste Super-Sprachregel, gilt:

> Sprache erfüllt genau dann ihren Zweck, wenn der Empfänger das versteht, was der Sender beabsichtigt.

Alle anderen Regeln sind dieser obersten Direktive untergeordnet, und sind im Grunde nur da, um eine möglichst widerspruchsfreie und konsistente Umwandlung von Nachrichten in Sprache und wieder zurück zu ermöglichen, ohne dass man vor jedem einzelnen Informationstransfer Codierungs- und Decodierungsvorschriften aushandeln muss. Das gesamte Rechtschreib- und Grammatik-Regelwerk stellt also nur eine Norm dar, die zum Ziel hat, die obengenannte Super-Regel möglichst immer zu erfüllen. (Mit allen Vor- und Nachteilen von Normen)

Besonders Werbetexter setzen sich aber sehr gerne, und mit voller Absicht über diese Normen hinweg, weil mit dem bewussten Verstoß gegen die Norm Aufmerksamkeit erregt wird, was im Sinn jedes Werbers ist.

Solange dabei die allerhöchste Super-Regel nicht verletzt wird, solange also die Werbetexte so verstanden werden, wie das von den Auftraggebern beabsichtigt ist, ist dagegen auch nichts einzuwenden. Denn all die vielen offiziellen Regeln sind allesamt nur unverbindliche Empfehlungen, an die sich in Wahrheit niemand halten muss. Davon ausgenommen sind nur Schüler (sofern sie im Rahmen des Unterrichts Texte verfassen) und einige Beamte (wenn sie amtliche Dokumente verfassen). Jeder andere darf sprechen und schreiben wie er oder sie will, muss bei Abweichungen von der Norm aber damit rechnen, nicht, oder falsch, verstanden zu werden.

Comment: Gibt es eine Quelle für die genannte "Super-Sprachregel"?

Comment: Also ich hab nicht das verstanden, was der Absender beabsichtigt hat - unterstelle ich mal. :-) **Ich** hab' nämlich keine Werbung gesehen die *"wir kennen uns in DE aus"* aussagt, sondern eine Werbung, die *"wir sind zu geizig um unsere Texte von einer vernünftigen Agentur erstellen zu lassen"* aussagt. Aber wahrscheinlich werd' ich einfach langsam alt. :-P

Comment: @IQV: Ja, die normative Kraft des Faktischen, bzw. der gesunde Menschenverstand.

Comment: Dem, dass ein benamter See einen Artikel hat, stimme ich zu. Dieser Artikel muss aber nicht immer verwendet werden, denn Sätze wie _»Der Feind steht zwischen Rhein und Bodensee«_ sind grammatikalisch korrekt.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Grammatisch ist der Satz korrekt, geographisch aber sehr problematisch. Der Rhein fließt nämlich durch den Bodensee durch. Da ist es dann schwierig, zwischen den beiden Gewässern zu stehen, wenn sie viele Kilometer lang identisch sind. (Der Rhein ist Grenzfluss zwischen der Schweiz und Österreich, fließt bei Bregenz für ein kurzes Stück ganz auf österreichischem Boden und mündet dort in den Bodensee. Der Fluss durchquert den See der Länge nach, und ungefähr bei Stein am Rhein geht der See wieder in einen Fluss über, und fließt von dort unter wieder unter dem Namen *Rhein* weiter.)

Answer (score 1):

Das *»zum«* wäre nötig, wenn besagter See das Ziel einer Reise wäre:

> Ich fahre per Anhalter von Berlin bis zum Bodensee.

In der Anzeige haben wir aber eine **Gebietsbeschreibung** mit zwei Ortsangaben, die das Gebiet begrenzen. Hier ist das *»zum«* verzichtbar, falsch wäre es natürlich nicht.

Zum Vergleich:

> Von Österreich bis Ungarn, von Plattensee bis Bodensee: Überall
>   pfeifen sie das gleiche Lied.
>
> Von Harz bis Allgäu – die Wölfe sind zurück.

Comment: Diese Antwort widerspricht der Antwort/Quelle von Hubert. Kann nicht erkennen, ob es so eine "Ziel" Regel gibt. Quelle?

Comment: @Martin: In meinem Duden _»Richtiges und gutes Deutsch«_ steht: _»Die Namen der Berge, Gebirge, Flüsse, Seen und Meere haben einen Artikel.«_ Ob dieser Artikel grundsätzlich verwendet werden muss oder ob es in manchen Fällen auch ohne geht, steht nicht dabei, dieses Detail ist an dieser Stelle nicht geregelt. So etwas wie _»Am Dienstag rase ich mit meiner Kiste von Berlin bis Bodensee«_ ist mir noch nicht begegnet, aber _»Der Feind steht zwischen Rhein und Bodensee«_ kommt ohne Artikel aus.

Comment: Ich glaube, das Problem ist, dass es gehen *kann*, wenn beide Dinge von der gleichen "Kategorie" sind (also entweder Landschaft / oder Stadt). Wenn die Aussage gemischte Typen enthält ("Berlin -> Bodensee") klingt es für *mich* grauslig.