# Is there any difference between "bis heute" and "bis zum heute"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is there any difference in the construction or the meaning of these 2 sentences?

> Es ist derselbe Verein, der sich auch heute noch um die Tiere kümmert.

and

> Es ist derselbe Verein, der sich bis zum heute noch um die Tiere kümmert

Comment: Yes, the second one is grammatically wrong. Is has read either *bis zum heutigen Tag* or *bis heute um die Tiere* (no *zum*, in both cases no *noch*). From the meaning there is no difference.

Comment: but why bis zum can not be used? I understood from a previous post that **bis** is when you make a range, while _bis zum_ is used when using a specific value!!
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/bis-oder-bis-zum

Comment: @Millen Read that answer carefully. "Bis zu" is used to specify a maximum value of **quantities** (Mengen). There cannot be more than exactly one "heute", so it doesn't fit into that pattern (in contrast to "bis zum heutigen Tag", where "Tag" is countable, and "heutig" merely modifies "Tag").

Comment: I did :-) I wrote the above note before I see the answer :-)

Comment: Now I understood: bis zum heute is not correct. But what about "bis" or 'bis zu" in other situations ..... could we use them interchangeably? for example in : Sie schlief bis Sonnenaufgang. Sie schlief bis zum Sonnenaufgang. Both are right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas the first sentence is completely fine:

> Es ist derselbe Verein, der sich **auch heute noch** um die Tiere kümmert.

your second sentence

> *Es ist derselbe Verein, der sich **bis zum heute noch** um die Tiere kümmert

is prima vista not a well-formed sentence in terms of standard German. It is not an established way of speaking to combine *heute* with *bis zum*. *Heute* goes simply with *bis*, so *bis heute* is correct.

Accepted and regularly used expressions are

> bis heute
>
> bis zum heutigen Tage

Simple reason: *zum* is derived from *zu dem*, which is *zu* plus definite article, and when there is a definite article, there has to be a noun. *Heute* is not a noun (usually).

This is the core of the answer. Now, for some intricacies:

I said "prima vista" because you can - theoretically - argue that in a certain way of thinking your second sentence is acceptable anyway. It is a little bit a form of twisted thinking, though. And you would have to write the *heute* as *Heute* with a capital H.

> Es ist derselbe Verein, der sich bis zum Heute noch um die Tiere kümmert

In this sentence, the *Heute* is used as a noun, and therefore you can say *bis zum Heute*. However, this is not how anybody would usually speak or write. It is more like a hypothetical sentence constructed in analogy with (more accepted, more well-formed) sentences such as:

> Wer das Gestern nicht kennt, verirrt sich im Heute.
>
> Im Gestern und im Heute entscheidet sich das Morgen.

As you may conclude from the broad-brush philosophy there, using *heute, gestern, morgen* as nouns is a little bit manieristic and would be met only in higher registers of speech.

Oh, and in order to answer **your actual question**: No, there is no difference of *meaning* between your sentences. The second sentence would usually be considered as ill-formed, but the meaning of it would be understood quite so as in the first (well-formed) sentence.

---

Uhh... and one thing more: if you juxtapose "noch heute" and "bis heute", and if you interpret things in a very subtle way, you may argue that

> noch heute

would tend to mean "started earlier, continues until today, and will continue in the future (or at least there is no end in sight)", whereas

> bis heute

could be understood (but not necessarily) as "started earlier, continued until today, and that's it, no continuation into the future". But this is a little bit of a muddy terrain here. You can also understand *bis heute* as continuing into the future anyway.

That's of course more about the meaning and usage of *noch* and *bis*.